# html5 video code is not working,doesn't show video

Tags: html

I've tried in opera,and IE.Didn't work.Tried with default controls setting and with mp4 videos too.no luck.
anyone please help.Where is the bug?
as i don't have enough reputation score to post an image,giving a link.please see the code there.
http://mridulahmed.net63.net/qwa.jpg

Comment: Don't post an image, post your code

Comment: I posted my code first,but it showed as normal text.how to post my code the way it should be?

Comment: Learn how to use StackExchange formatting (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or show your code in a site like jsbin or jsfiddle. You say you tried it with mp4, but your screen capture shows an avi which won't work. Try another file off the web like this: http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine as I have tested it , you just need to use .mp4 file format or other HTML5 supported file formats.

Only safari can play AVI format files ( which is only when Quick time is installed on your pc ) otherwise an AVI file cannot be played on an html5  tag in any browser.

Solution to this is to convert your video to  web supported format. HTML5 supports :

```
MP4 = MPEG 4 files with H264 video codec and AAC audio codec
WebM = WebM files with VP8 video codec and Vorbis audio codec
Ogg = Ogg files with Theora video codec and Vorbis audio codec
```